# End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed session

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize a string array in c# but getting this error -

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : End of Stream
> encountered before parsing was completed.

Here is my code:

```
void SerializeFunc(ISession session, string key, object toSerialize)
{
  var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
  var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, toSerialize);
  session.Set(key, memoryStream.ToArray());
  memoryStream.Flush();
  memoryStream.Close();
  memoryStream.Dispose();
}

object DeSerializeFunc(ISession session, string key)
{
  var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
  var objectBytes = session.Get(key) as byte[];
  memoryStream.Write(objectBytes, 0, objectBytes.Length);
  memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  memoryStream.Position = 0;
  var valueObject = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream); //ERROR
  memoryStream.Close();
  memoryStream.Dispose();
  return valueObject;
}

public class CustomSession : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession
{
  Dictionary<string, object> sessionStorage = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  void ISession.Set(string key, byte[] value)
  {
    sessionStorage[key] = value;
  }
  bool ISession.TryGetValue(string key, out byte[] value)
  {
        if (sessionStorage[key] != null)
        {
            value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sessionStorage[key].ToString());
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            value = null;
            return false;
        }
   }
   // remove other Interface members for simplicity..
}

var session = new CustomSession();
SerializeFunc(session, "key1", new string[] { "one", "two", "three" });
var obj = DeSerializeFunc(session, "key1"); //ERROR
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `Flush` before you grab the bytes out of the stream?

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to flush a `MemoryStream`. But we could do with knowing more debugging details - did you look at `objectBytes` in the debugger? Does it have a reasonable amount of data? (Note that in `DeSerializeFunc`, it would be simpler just to use `var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(objectBytes);` instead of writing the bytes and then rewinding the stream.)

Comment: Sam, please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question. In particular there is no problem with MemoryStream or deserialization parts of your code - so that part is totally unnecessary in the code shown. The interesting part how your "session" code is setup is totally missing... overall make sure code in the post actually can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried with your suggestion but the error is still the same. This is what I did: 
`var objectBytes = session.Get(key) as byte[]; 

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(objectBytes)`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov updated the code to show my session implementation as suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @Sam: Yes, I didn't say that would solve the problem - just that it would be simpler code. But you didn't answer my question about data in the debugger...

Comment: @JonSkeet ah got it. Yes I see the data however array looks different between set & get calls. Looks like **ISession.TryGetValue** method is messed up.

Comment: `bool ISession.TryGetValue(string key, out byte[] value)` makes absolutely no sense. Are you sure that the right code? (Definitely explains why nothing is working... but *why* one would do that to themselves?) Also you did not read [MCVE] guidance... which is sad. There is way too much code in the post that unrelated to issue you see - all serialization/deserialization should be removed, all session stuff is unnecessary, just get/set methods of your CustomSession class with an assert that Get returns exactly the same (Assert.SequnceEqual) bytes is all that is needed - 10 lines max.

Comment: thanks @JonSkeet and Alexei for the pointers. It is working now!